# How to evaluate $\Bbb E [\frac{1}{\bar{X}}]$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $$f(x|\theta) = \theta e^{-\theta x} $$ Consider $n$ iid random variables $X_1,...,X_n$, where each $X_i \sim \text{exponential}(\theta)$

How do I evaluate $\Bbb E [\frac{1}{\bar{X}}]$?

It would be a lot easier if it were $\Bbb E [\bar{X}]$ because I would get $\frac{1}{n} \sum_i \Bbb E [X_i]$. But that doesn't work when considering the inverse of the sample mean, so I am confused how to manipulate the expression to get the expected value term written in terms of $\theta$.

Comment: do you know that if $Z = X+Y$ the sum of two independent r.v.  then $f_Z(x) = f_X \ast f_Y(x)$ the convolution product of the pdf ? then $f_{\overline{X}} = \underbrace{f \ast \ldots \ast f}_{n}(x)$ where $f(x) = \theta e^{-x\theta}1_{x > 0}$. using the Laplace transform, you get $f_{\overline{X}}(x) = C x^{n-1} e^{- \theta x} 1_{x > 0}$ where $C$ is the normalization factor such that $\int_0^\infty f_{\overline{X}}(x) dx = 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $S_n := X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ has gamma distribution:

$$ f_{S_n}(x) = \frac{\theta^n x^{n-1} e^{-\theta x}}{(n-1)!}. $$

Now you can use this to compute

$$ \Bbb{E}( \bar{X}^{-1}) = n \Bbb{E}( S_n^{-1} ) = n \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \, f_{S_n}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{n \theta}{n-1}. $$

Comment: I wonder if using the invariance properties of the exponential distribution, we could obtain directly the result ?

Comment: @user1952009  what do u mean?

Comment: @user1952009 I agree that the scaling property of exponential distribution gives $\Bbb{E}(1/\bar{X}_n) = C_n \theta$ for some constant $C_n$ depending on $n$, but I am not sure if this idea is enough to determine $C_n$ without further computation.

Comment: What happens if $n=1$?

Comment: @StanShunpike, For $n = 1$ the expectation diverges. This is somehow hinted from the result above (which is true for $n \geq 2$), but of course it can be checked separately.